# algorithm to find places in sorted array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a sorted array of keys and value like

```
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 65
                ......
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 65
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [value] => 35
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [value] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [value] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [value] => 0
            )
)
```

I search for simple algorithm that run over this array and return array of places
like :

```
places['1'] = keys => array(1,0), value => 65
places['2'] = keys => array(5),   value => 35
places['3'] = keys => array(4),   value => 3
places['4'] = keys => array(2,3), value => 0
```

so in the first place we have key 1 + 0, and the value is 65
and so on.......

I try to loop with `foreach` and add a lot of `if` conditions,
I search something simple

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `places['4']` in the last line. If so, this should do it (otherwise you have to explain why there is a `2` ;)):

```
$placeIndex = 0;
$lastValue = null;
$places = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['value'] === $lastValue) {
        $places[$placeIndex]['keys'][] = $key;
    }
    else {
        $placeIndex++;
        $lastValue = $value['value'];
        $places[$placeIndex] = array(
            'keys' => array($key),
            'value' => $lastValue
        );
    }
}
```